# Best way to reference a certain variable throughout the namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, global-variables

I have a `mainForm` variable that is used nearly everywhere in my program. I'd like to be able to reference to this variable without having to type the name of the class that holds this variable (i.e. instead of `Global._mainForm`, I should be able to just type `_mainForm` to access this variable anywhere within the same namespace).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anytime I see a global anything I get worried, so I would reconsider how your program is architected. You can almost always get away without having a globally accessible object. Although there are legitimate reasons to have a globally accessible object, usually I try to stay away from them.

From the little information you've given, you might be able to use events to talk to the main window instead of directly accessing it.

If you do have real need for a globally accessible object then you could do something like this

**Note:** In the code below everything is static, conversely you could create a special static class that holds a reference to the instance of the class you're really interested in. But there is no way that I'm aware of to hold a global reference that is outside of all namespaces to an instance of an object.

```
using Bar = ProbablyAReallyBadIdeaToHaveAGlobalAnythingButHeyWhyNot.TestClass;

namespace ProbablyAReallyBadIdeaToHaveAGlobalAnythingButHeyWhyNot
{
  public static class TestClass
  {
    public static int TestFoo { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace Foo.SomeOtherNamespace
{
  class MyClassThatDoesStuff
  {
    public void DoStuff()
    {
      Bar.TestFoo = 123;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This requires qualification of TestFoo with the type alias 'Bar' introduced by the using statement.  OP wants to access TestFoo without qualification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish this in C#.

Namespaces are simply part of the type name of a class.  Lexically, you can think of a namespace as containing only other namespaces and classes.

Classes may contain fields, functions, events, properties, nested classes, etc., but not nested namespaces.

Therefore there is no way to to define a symbol in a namespace outside of class that aliases or refers to a symbol contained in a specific class.

When resolving the reference to the variable name `_mainForm`, the only place that it does not require additional qualification is from within the scope of the class that it is defined in.

If you are in a namespace scope that is the same as as the class that defines `_mainForm` (and `_mainForm` is a static instance), then you only need access it by qualifying it with the class name.  Otherwise you will require additional namespace qualification, or perhaps trickery with a `using` directive.  But outside of the containing class, you will always require a qualification of some kind to access `_mainForm`.

See http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_10.7_Scopes for excruciating detail.

Comment: Please read the MSDN documentation on the `using` statement. You also seem to have misread the question.

Comment: @ColeJohnson You can't use `using` directive to alias a static field in a class.  Therefore OP *won't* "be able to just type _mainForm to access this variable anywhere within the same namespace".  From MSDN: "The scope of a using directive is limited to the file in which it appears. Create a using alias to make it easier to qualify an identifier to a namespace or type."

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes, you can shorten the type name with an alias.  But you can't eliminate it.  OP wants to eliminate it which is not possible.  Zipper's answer does not specify that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see, in C#, for every class in a namespace to be able to directly address the same variable is by defining the variable as static in a base class used by all other classes in the namespace.  Since static variables can be addressed as local variables within the class (or classes inheriting from) they are defined in, the variable will be available without class qualifications.

Can't say it is a good idea, but that's not what you asked ...